# How to display a tag that displays when dragging content in html5?

Tags: jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

Is there a way to create a div that follows the mouse around when you are dragging something on your web site?

I want the div to only become visible when the user drags content that has been set to draggable.

I really just want a super simple and easy way to change the dragging item from just a ghost image to something different that I can style.

Thanks,
Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a hidden div on your html body, then when dragging you can set the css 'display' property to 'block', and finally using the clientx and clienty properties of the mouse event with a little javascript to reposition the div.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Do you think that this could/should be done using an onMouseDown event? like: onmousedown="showDraggingDiv();"

Comment: You need to combine the mouse events to show, hide and move the div, actually mousedown shows the div, mouseup hides the div and mousemove translates the div.

Comment: Here is what I came up with from the help from you and also another post: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/hj57k/509/)